# How do i cleanup my htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

A project i'm working on has a large htaccess file. But i'm sensing most of it is unneccary, yet i don't know how to use htaccess files at all.

How do i clean up this file?
Is there anything i should be aware of in this file?

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /404
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    # Remove extra trailing slashes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
    # Manage Uploads Directory
    RewriteRule /(uploads/.*) $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/javascript
    <filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|jpg|png|gif|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesmatch>
</ifModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|tpl)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 week"
  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 week"
  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"
  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"
  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 week"
  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 30 seconds"
  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 week"
  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 week"
  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't look that bad. It might be possible to consolidate some of the `ExpiresByType` directives.

Comment: In other words, I don't see a lot of redundancies in here.

Comment: What are the duplicate ExpiresByType?

Comment: I thought that ExpiresByType could be listed with wildcards, but the docs seem to indicate that is not the case. Maybe these can't be consolidated http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what you actually want, and then read the [documentation for htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) and the various Apache modules.

Comment: I want the same thing this file does, but i feel that it requires cleanup. It's a little large.